# Provide a background image to the Toolbar in navigation page

Tags: image, background, toolbar, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.forms, I am unable to provide a background image to the navigation tool bar.
I am able to set the Title and add a right button on the toolbar using ToolbarItems.Add(...).
My code snippet is as below

public class App : Application

{

public App ()

{

MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Home());

}

}

public class Home : ContentPage
{
public Home ()

{

this.Title = "MyHeader";

ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem{...});

}

}

Please suggest the ways to provide the background image on the nav tool bar.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [NavigationPage](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage/) you can set only:

- BarBackgroundColor
- BarTextColor

for the navigation toolbar. You should probably write your [CustomRenderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Can u please help me with its related sample. I know i have to create a custom renderer for that but dont know how to create it for the toolbaritem. Thank You for your reply :)

Comment: First of all you have to provide us what were you trying to achieve this. At this moment you are asking for ready and complete solution.

Comment: i want to achieve a custom renderer for toolbar to set a background image in it. and i dont know how to set a custom renderer for a toolbar. I need a reference more specifically than a complete solution. Thank You :)

Comment: Maybe check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008642/xamarin-forms-change-background-color-of-navigation-bar. Mainly you need a `CustomRenderer` for `NavigationPage` I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. It eventually worked out. Thanx a ton :)

Comment: Great! Please remember about upvoting!